# Creating daily % change in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am maintaining a tracker of sorts for enterprise wide. Recently my manager came to me with a request that he wants to see daily change against each of the respective business unit. The challenge is information is updated in real time and I don't have a time stamp to calculate the instance to be taken for calculation. Is there any way in Google Sheets to do that ?

Pasting the image below for better understanding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT6AG.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to copy the data from yesterday to another column, so that a % variation can be calculated in another column? I guess this % variation would be updated every day, and the data for previous days would be deleted?

Comment: Yes so essentially want that the data from live counter gets copied to the corresponding date column. Instead of % variation, even absolute number is fine. In that case the objective becomes that the corresponding date data should be copied from live data

Answer (score 1):

Make a short script that copy as values 'Cases (Live)' to 'Previous day Instance' column. And then put a trigger on that function to be activated each day at 23:59. Put a link to your project to go further. Example :

```
function histo(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('my Sheet');
  var range = sheet.getRange('B5:B9');
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange('D5'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
}
```

to define a trigger based on time

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every day at 06:00AM CT.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('histo')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(6)
      .create();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: How to do that ? How to create a short script ?

Comment: Provide a link to your project or show more informations in your screenshot : name of sheet, column, row ...

Comment: how to add trigger function ?
Or alternatively you can tell you good source to study about Scripting language

Comment: To create a trigger, go to script editor, then select the clock on the left hand side and follow instructions -or- active one time the function I have added in my proposal : see createTimeDrivenTriggers